# How to drag and drop layouts in android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I have a parent vertical linear layout. in that i have 10 vertical linear layouts. i wan to drag and drop with those 10 vertical layout like drag and drop listview am new to android please help me.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FF8989"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/dragtext" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Drag quick" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFCC00"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Drag soon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Drag upon" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Drag me" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Draging" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FF8989"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Drag out"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Drag in"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFCC00"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Draged"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Drag_1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Drag_2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Drag_3"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FF8989"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Drag_4"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Drag_5"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFCC00"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Drag_6"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Drag_7"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Drag_8"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView18"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Drag_9"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FF8989"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView19"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Drag_10"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Drag_11"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

//java file

here am implement onDragListener and onTouchListener and i set setOnDragListener to every layout

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View layoutview, DragEvent dragevent) {
        int action = dragevent.getAction();
        switch (action) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag event started");
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag event entered into " + layoutview.toString());
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag event exited from " + layoutview.toString());

            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:

            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            Log.d(LOGCAT, "Dropped");

            LinearLayout dragged = (LinearLayout) dragevent.getLocalState();
            LinearLayout target = (LinearLayout) layoutview;
            int t = target.getNextFocusUpId();
            int d = target.getNextFocusDownId();
            View view = (View) dragevent.getLocalState();
            ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            owner.removeView(view);
            target .addView(view);

            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag ended");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

But it doesn't work when dragout whole layout(parent layout) are drag and invisible. am new and am struggling please help me.